# Monaco Editor Update Completion Items [Angular]

Tags: angular, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

I am trying to use the monaco editor in an angular 10 app via ngx-monaco-editor. This is a monaco editor question more than an angular question (I think)...I'm new to using this editor.

I'm trying to provide different completion items to 2 different files and I'm calling my language **'myLang'**.

- File 1 needs to have RULE1 as a completion item
- File 2 needs to have RULE2 as a completion item

Both files are open with `{language:'myLang'}`

The rules are dynamic and can change so I need to update them dynamically.

So far I have been able to register a static list (even a dynamic list) of completion items on the 'window.monaco.languages' but how can I tell the editor (or the editor model) to use List1 for File 1 and List2 for File 2

In a more general question when you open 2 different js files, they will have different contexts. The variable names / function names are different for example. How do you tell monaco editor what completion items to use depending on what file is open (how do you pass all the available context: variables/functions/identifiers) to each file that's open in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Well, typically you *parse* the contents of the document when Monaco opens it or when the user modifies it. You may also *cache* the resulting tree until the document is modified (to avoid needlessly parsing it again).

By parsing the document, you can recognize which elements are, for example, class names, function names, etc. depending on your language.